# Total the amount within a group and don't include duplicate values

Tags: oracle, rtf, bi-publisher

I'm creating a report in Oracle 12c BI Publisher using a RTF Template and having an issue which is I want a grand total in the bottom of the report which will compute all the amount but will not include the duplicate value. For example I have a table consists of:

```
ID  NAME  TRANSACTION_NO1  AMOUNT1  TRANSACTION_NO2  AMOUNT2
1   A     111              12,000   121              23,000
2   A     112              14,000   121              23,000
3   A     113              16,000   121              23,000
4   B     114              11,000   122              11,000
                                         SubTotal:   80,000
```

You can see above that the `121` in column `Transaction_No2` has a multiple values but different `transaction_no1` so that it Computes all the amount in `amount2` which is the SubTotal should be 34,000 only if it will not sum the value that has a duplicate value.

I'm using the below code to compute the total amount:

`<?sum(current-group()/AMOUNT2)?>`

And by the way I group it by name.

Comment: Can you give more details on why this needs to be done? Seems like an odd request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to sum distinct values. Look here for clue : https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/counting-distinctly

Comment: Hi. I try this one and it works. ```<?sum(xdoxslt:distinct_values(current-group()/AMOUNT2))?>``` Thanks!

Comment: @Lawrencxe be aware that the result will be wrong if you have 2 different transactions for the same number in AMOUNT2.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?for-each-group:MainQueryName;./Transaction_No2?>
    <?sum(current-group()/AMOUNT2)?>
<?end for-each-group?>
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this one but it still compute the duplicate values. But anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Lawrencxe You did replace 'MainQueryName' by the query that has the transction grouping? You could always use `xdoxslt:set_variable` and `xdoxslt:get_variable` to save the last `Transaction_No2` and compare it the current one and then only add `AMOUNT2` to another variable if they differ.